# Do shell command in detached screen and detach again

Tags: shell, unix, gnu-screen

Is it possible to enter into detached screen, do command, and detach again via one shell command?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach

Comment: Screen does not work for me. I use tmux and send-keys method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using [tmux](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

Start screen command:

```
tmux new -s nameOfScreen
```

And for running commands on detached screen I used send-keys method:

`tmux send-keys -t tab "command" Enter`